# Mathematica MonomialList Not Working

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

Thank you in advance for any and all help with my problem!

I'm writing a function and part of the function is to separate `q^2 P[1, 7] P[3, 9] P[4, 6] + (P[1, 6] P[3, 9] P[4, 7])/q - 
 2 q P[1, 6] P[3, 9] P[4, 7] - q^3 P[1, 7] P[3, 4] P[6, 9] + 
 q^2 P[1, 3] P[4, 7] P[6, 9] + q^2 P[1, 6] P[3, 4] P[7, 9]` into a comma-separated monomial list via the function `MonomialList`.

Within the package that I am using in conjunction with my function, `q` and `P[_Integer, _Integer]` are defined as objects. `MonomialList` fails to separate the above polynomial and yields `{q^2 P[1, 7] P[3, 9] P[4, 6] + (P[1, 6] P[3, 9] P[4, 7])/q - 
  2 q P[1, 6] P[3, 9] P[4, 7] - q^3 P[1, 7] P[3, 4] P[6, 9] + 
  q^2 P[1, 3] P[4, 7] P[6, 9] + q^2 P[1, 6] P[3, 4] P[7, 9]}`

I've tried using the additional argument in the `MonomialList` function to specify the variable but to no avail. Can somebody please help me achieve a monomial list from the polynomial. If anyone knows of a better way than `MonomialList`, by all means, suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that Mathematica doesn't recognize your expression as a polynomial (which you can verify with `PolynomialQ[expression]`) due to the `q^-1` term. Fortunately, there is another easy option. The `Collect` function will take your expression and group terms with the same power of `q`, and because this is a sum expression, we can convert it to a list with the apply operator:

```
yourMonomialList = List @@ Collect[yourExpression, q]
```

Comment: But will this work when I have monomials that do not have any power of q as a coefficient?

Comment: You can replace `q` with a list of variables you want to collect by.